# ANTLR, heterogeneous AST problem

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I examine heterogeneous trees in ANTLR (using ANTLRWorks 1.4.2).

Here is the example of what I have already done in ANTLR.

```
grammar test;

options {
    language = java;
    output = AST;
}

tokens {
    PROGRAM;
    VAR;
}

@members {
    class Program extends CommonTree {
        public Program(int ttype) {
            token = new CommonToken(ttype, "<start>");
        }
    }
}

start
    :    program var function
        // Works fine:
        //->    ^(PROGRAM program var function)

        // Does not work (described below):
        ->    ^(PROGRAM<Program> program var function)
    ;

program
    :    'program'! ID ';'!
    ;

var
    :    TYPE^ ID ';'!
    ;

function
    :    ID '('! ')'! ';'!
    ;

TYPE
    :    'int'
    |    'string'
    ;

ID
    :    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
    ;

WHITESPACE
    :    (' ' | '\t' '\n'| '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Sample input:

```
program foobar;
int foo;
bar();
```

When I use rewrite rule `^(PROGRAM<Program> program var function)`, ANTLR stumbles over and I get AST like this:

[image: AntLR]

Whereas when I use this rewrite rule `^(PROGRAM program var function)` it works:

[image]

1. Could anyone explain where am I wrong, please? Frankly, I do not really get the idea of heterogeneous trees and how do I use `<…>` syntax in ANTLR.
2. What do `r0` and `r1` mean (first picture)?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't just mix `< ... >` inside rewrite rules: you have either `output=AST;` or `output=template;` defined in the `options{...}` section, not both. So you either generate an AST, or are generating (source) code with the StringTemplate engine. What exactly are you tying to do here anyway? What is your goal?

Comment: @Bart Thanks for the comment & edit! Based on [example here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction#Treeconstruction-heterogeneous), I _can_ mix `<…>` and rewrite rules. My goal is to build _heterogeneous AST_ (as the part of assignment). As far as I understand (it is tricky!), I have to implement my own tree and AST nodes. No `Java` code is necessary at this point (except for the code in the `@members` section). Spent two days, no luck so far.

Comment: Aha, this is new v3.1+ syntax: my ANTLR book (compliant with v3.0) only mentions `< ... >` in combination with `output=template`. Thanks for the link. I don't have time at the moment to go through it, but I will later on (tomorrow probably) and get back to you.

Comment: @Bart Thank you. What book do you mean? I have this one — «The Definitive ANTLR Reference» (The Pragmatic Programmers), although did not find any useful information.

Comment: Yeah sorry, "the ANTLR book"is indeed _The Definitive ANTLR Reference_ from Prag-Prog. In there, `< ... >` is only used in chapter 9, _Generating Structured Text with Templates and Grammars_, where you need to set `output=template` in the options section. This new feature isn't handled, AFAIK.

Comment: @Bart This feature (together with heterogeneous trees) is briefly described in other Pragmatic book called «Language Implementation Patterns» (also by Terence Parr). A chapter about heterogeneous ASTs is published [here](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/patterns.pdf). (_just FYI_)

Comment: Thanks, I have the book, but, as you can see, haven't read it from cover to cover yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what these `r0` and `r1` mean: I don't use ANTLRWorks for debugging, so can't comment on that.

Also, `language = java;` causes ANTLR 3.2 to produce the error:

> error(10):  internal error: no such group file java.stg
>
> error(20):  cannot find code generation templates java.stg 
>   error(10):  internal error: no such group file java.stg
>
> error(20):  cannot find code generation templates java.stg

ANTLR 3.2 expects it to be `language = Java;` (capital "J"). But, by default the target is Java, so, mind as well remove the `language = ...` entirely.

Now, as to you problem: I cannot reproduce it. As I mentioned, I tested it with ANTLR 3.2, and removed the `language = java;` part from your grammar, after which everything went as (I) expected.

Enabling the rewrite rule `-> ^(PROGRAM<Program> program var function)` produces the following ATS:

[image]

and when enabling the rewrite rule `-> ^(PROGRAM program var function)` instead, the following AST is created:

[image]

I tested both rewrite rules this with the following class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("program foobar; int foo; bar();");
        testLexer lexer = new testLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        testParser parser = new testParser(tokens);
        testParser.start_return returnValue = parser.start();
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)returnValue.getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

And the images are produced using [graph.gafol.net](http://graph.gafol.net/) (and the output of the `Main` class, of course).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and efforts, Bart. I appreciate it! Second of all. I got it (my assignment) all wrong. I should have done AST construction NOT in `@members` section, but in separate `.java` classes. And, finally, as it turned out, `ANTLRWorks` is unsuitable tool for the tasks like this. It took me 6 days to try and completely move from `ANTLRWorks` to old good command-line interface. :-) Plus, for some reason, `ANTLRWorks` would inherit `MyGrammarParser` from `DebugParser` instead of `Parser`. (But, despite everything, `ANTLRWorks` deals fine with everything else).

Comment: And, regarding your answer. You are right about `language = java;`. When dealing with Java, better do not use it at all. Next, `-> ^(PROGRAM<Program> program var function)` works as I expected too (but, again, not in `ANTLRWorks`).

Comment: @Little Jeans, you're welcome. Yeah, I use ANTLRWorks only for editing grammars. Generating the lexer/parser and debugging them, I also do from the command line.